# jquery element select on keyboard keypress code

Tags: jquery

I have a `ul` list and I want to change the background color of li when I press a key on keyboard. Example. I press `a` on keyboard and change the background of li which text was `a`.

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Which is the best and simple way to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
var li = $("ul li");

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
     li
      .filter(function() { 
         return $(this).text() == String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
      })
      .css("background-color", "#f00");
});
```

Comment: This solution is great. I modified a bit String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase().

Comment: @kst Ah yes, I forgot that they're always returned as uppercase. I'll make the edit too.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass event as argument inside `keypress` and then using `event.which` you can then track which `key` is pressed after that check if `li` contains that word using `jQuery:contain();`

**Example**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
   var keypressed = e.which;

   //process for checking pressed key value 
   $('ul li:contains('+ returned value of above process +')').css(
   {
      'background-color':'red'
   });
});
```

Comment: @down-voter somebody please explain it so i can correct myself

Comment: I would guess because your answer is incomplete. You leave out the part with the explanation regarding how to pass the pressed character to the selector...

Comment: @netrunner what was my intention is let the OP do itself because giving code is not what SO is meant for...i just wanted to let OP to learn how can he/she can do that.

Comment: While agree to some extent ("is not what SO is meant for..."), your answer probably was a bit confusing to the OP, since you only vaguely describe what should happen with `keypressed` on your comment. That's probably why the OP accepted the other answer...

Answer (score 0):

I would first build a map of li so they're easily found and so that the heavy computation of the texts doesn't have to be done at each key press, then just test the key on keypress :

```
var map = {};
$('li').each(function(){
   var key = $(this).text().trim();
   if (key.length==1) map[key]=$(this);
});
console.log(map);
$(window).keypress(function(e){
  var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  if (map[key]) map[key].css('background-color','red');
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ufufoj/1/edit)